# Zoom monad stack maintaining context

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

Time for my weekly lens question;

I have a monad stack:

```
newtype Action a = Action
  { runAct :: StateT ActionState (ReaderT Hooks IO) a
  } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState ActionState, MonadReader Hooks, MonadIO)

data ActionState = ActionState
  { _ed :: Editor
  , _asyncs :: [AsyncAction]
  }
```

I used [`makeClassy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makeClassy) on the `Editor` type to generate a `HasEditor` typeclass which my editor lenses depend on.

An `Editor` has many `Buffer`s; I've defined another monad stack type for an action that acts over a specific buffer (a `BufAction`); the only difference is that the StateT is over a `Buffer`:

```
newtype BufAction a = BufAction
  { runBufAct::StateT Buffer (ReaderT Hooks IO) a
  } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState Buffer, MonadReader Hooks, MonadIO)
```

to run a `BufAction` I use `zoom (editor.buffers.ix selected)` to zoom the StateT to a specific buffer; but the issue is that now inside the `BufAction` I can no longer use any lenses that operate over `editor` or require `HasEditor`.

Ideally all `Action`s run inside a `BufAction` without lifting, while `BufAction`s cannot run inside an `Action`. In this case `BufAction` would require the full `ActionState`, but also a reference to a specific buffer in order to run; whereas `Action` just requires the `ActionState`; so `BufAction` is a more restrictive Monad and `Action`s should be embeddable in it.

So approximately I want some sort of type like this:

```
newtype Action a = forall s. HasEditor s => Action
  { runAct :: StateT s (ReaderT Hooks IO) a
  } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState s, MonadReader Hooks, MonadIO)
```

However GHC chokes on this; it can't handle existentials and constraints in a newtype;

I switched it to a `data` type; but then I lose GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving and need to implement all of those deriving
clauses manually; which I'd really rather not do.

I've also tried using a type alias; which would mean I don't need to derive typeclasses, but since I also embed Actions
in other datatypes I run into errors; for example since I use `Action` here:

```
data ActionState = ActionState
{ _ed :: Editor
, _asyncs :: [Async (Action ())]
, _hooks :: Hooks
, _nextHook :: Int
}
```

I run into:

```
• Illegal polymorphic type: Action ()
  GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism
• In the definition of data constructor ‘ActionState’
  In the data type declaration for ‘ActionState’
```

Taking a different tact; I've also tried implementing a flexible MonadState instance:

```
instance (HasEditor s, HasBuffer s) => (MonadState s) BufAction where
```

but get:

```
• Illegal instance declaration for ‘MonadState s BufAction’
    The coverage condition fails in class ‘MonadState’
      for functional dependency: ‘m -> s’
    Reason: lhs type ‘BufAction’ does not determine rhs type ‘s’
    Un-determined variable: s
• In the instance declaration for ‘(MonadState s) BufAction’
```

Because MonadState uses functional dependencies...

Really stuck on this one and I could use a hand!

Thanks for taking a look! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Your question's kind of unclear. You say "all `Action`s work inside a `BufAction` without lifting, while `BufAction`s cannot run inside an `Action`" - how would this work, when `BufAction`'s state is smaller than `Action`'s state? Surely it should be the other way round?

Comment: Sorry that it's unclear; I'll attempt to explain a little better. Correct, BufAction uses a smaller state than `Action`, but it's not so much a 'smaller state' as it is a state with 'more information'. We can think of the state available to `BufAction` as `(ActionState, BufId)`; essentially the entire `ActionState` is available (just like `Action`) but we have info that lets us focus a specific buffer as well. So any `Action`s which operate over `ActionState` should still be available in `BufAction`; but `BufAction`s require the `BufId` context and can't run in an `Action`. Any clearer?

Comment: This means of course we'll have to change the state which the BufAction acts over to something that actually contains the larger state; but that's what the `HasEditor` and `HasBuffer` constraints refer to; `Action` should be run over a state with only `HasEditor`; while `BufAction` should be run over state with `HasEditor` AND `HasBuffer`, so it's more restrictive.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you have `type Buffer = (ActionState, BufId)` and you want to compose a `State ActionState` with a `State Buffer`? What's wrong with `zoom _1`?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson That actually should work; but the trouble is in specifying the actual types of the monad stack; If I want my `Action` Monad stack to work in both `BufAction` stack and `Action` stacks I need the stack to be generic enough; i.e. something like `newtype Action a = forall s. HasEditor s => Action (StateT s IO a)`; but you can't have existentials in your newtype; You can do it for a `data` type, but then I lose GeneralizedNewType deriving and have to write instances for (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState s, MonadIO) myself; which I could do; but I'd rather not.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I rewrote the second half of the question to reflect a few other (failed) attempts at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is what you're trying to do to me. The constraints about what kind of state is acceptable in an Action will be specified on definitions using Action, not action itself. Then you'll be able to use the `zoom` function from the lens package to focus on different `Buffer`s in your `Editor`, for example.

```
{-# Language TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# Language GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# Language FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# Language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# Language UndecidableInstances #-} -- for the Zoomed type instance

module Demo where

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Lens

data Hooks

data SomeState = SomeState
  { _thing1, _thing2 :: Int }

makeLenses ''SomeState

newtype Action s a = Action
  { runAct :: StateT s (ReaderT Hooks IO) a
  } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState s)

instance Zoom (Action a) (Action s) a s where
  zoom l (Action m) = Action (zoom l m)

type instance Zoomed (Action s) = Zoomed (StateT s (ReaderT Hooks IO))

example :: Action Int a -> Action SomeState a
example = zoom thing1
```